# Binary operators and align environment

Tags: align, math-operators

A code like this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

%logical equivalence
\newcommand{\eq}{\mathbin{\Leftrightarrow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & (true \eq true) \\
 \eq& (false \eq false) \\
 \eq& true \\
   =& true = true
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Displays this:

[image]

As you can see, both equal et equivalence symbol does not provide a spacing when an alignement marker `&` is in the way.
A definition of `\eq` like that would:

```
\newcommand{\eq}{\ \Leftrightarrow\ }
```

But it doesn't seem proper and wouldn't fix operators such as `=`.
So is there a way to have a spacing after a binary operators followed by a alignement marker?

Comment: You want `{}\eq{}&` and `={}&` But why `\mathbin` and not `\mathrel`?

Comment: After more careful research, `\mathrel` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Also why should I bother writing each time `{}\eq{}&` if I could just use this definition `\newcommand{\eq}{\ \Leftrightarrow\ }` ?

Comment: Because you don't want those spaces in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `\mathbin` is not the appropriate math type.

It's a common problem when you want the alignment point after a relation symbol. In this case you need to add `{}` in order to have an empty ordinary atom that triggers the correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%logical equivalence
\newcommand{\eq}{\Leftrightarrow} % \Leftrightarrow is \mathrel

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & (\mathit{true} \eq \mathit{true}) \\
 \eq{}& (\mathit{false} \eq \mathit{false}) \\
 \eq{}& \mathit{true} \\
   ={}& \mathit{true} = \mathit{true}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]